# numpy apply along axis not working with weekday

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, weekday

I have a numpy array:

```
>>> type(dat)
Out[41]: numpy.ndarray

>>> dat.shape
Out[46]: (127L,)

>>> dat[0:3]
Out[42]: array([datetime.date(2010, 6, 11), datetime.date(2010, 6, 19), datetime.date(2010, 6, 30)], dtype=object)
```

I want to get weekdays for each date in this array like the following:

```
>>> dat[0].weekday()
Out[43]: 4
```

I tried using the following but none work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

np.apply_along_axis(weekday,0,dat)
NameError: name 'weekday' is not defined

np.apply_along_axis(dt.weekday,0,dat)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'weekday'

np.apply_along_axis(pd.weekday,1,dat)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'weekday'

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.weekday(),0,dat)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'weekday'

np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.dt.weekday,0,dat)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: `weekday` is a method of the `datetime.date` object.  `apply_along_axis` expects a function.  Just do your calculation with a list comprehension.  Even if you could get it working, `apply_along_axis` won't speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.apply_along_axis` doesn't make much sense with a 1d array.  In a 2d or higher array, it applies the function to 1d slices from that array.  Regarding that function:

> This function should accept 1-D arrays. It is applied to 1-D
>           slices of `arr` along the specified axis.

This `nameerror` is produced even before running `apply`.  You didn't define a `weekday` function:

```
np.apply_along_axis(weekday,0,dat)
NameError: name 'weekday' is not defined
```

`weekday` is a method of a date, not a function in the `dt` module:

```
np.apply_along_axis(dt.weekday,0,dat)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

It's not defined in pandas either:

```
np.apply_along_axis(pd.weekday,1,dat)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

This looks better, but `apply_along_axis` passes an array (1d) to the `lambda`.  `weekday` isn't an array method.

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.weekday(),0,dat)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

And an array doesn't have a `dt` attribute either.

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: x.dt.weekday,0,dat)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

So let's forget about `apply_along_axis`.

---

Define a sample, first as list, and then as object array:

```
In [231]: alist = [datetime.date(2010, 6, 11), datetime.date(2010, 6, 19), datetime.date(2010, 6, 30)]
In [232]: data = np.array(alist)
In [233]: data
Out[233]: 
array([datetime.date(2010, 6, 11), datetime.date(2010, 6, 19),
       datetime.date(2010, 6, 30)], dtype=object)
```

And for convenience a lambda version of `weekday`:

```
In [234]: L = lambda x: x.weekday()
```

This can be applied iteratively in several ways:

```
In [235]: [L(x) for x in alist]
Out[235]: [4, 5, 2]
In [236]: [L(x) for x in data]
Out[236]: [4, 5, 2]
In [237]: np.vectorize(L)(data)
Out[237]: array([4, 5, 2])
In [238]: np.frompyfunc(L,1,1)(data)
Out[238]: array([4, 5, 2], dtype=object)
```

I just did time tests on a 3000 item list.  The list comprehension was fastest (as I expected from past tests), but the time differences were not large.  The biggest time consumer was simply running `x.weekday()` 3000 times.

Comment: alist throws TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Answer (score 1):

You could try vectorizing the weekday function so you can apply it elementwise to arrays.

```
weekday_func = lambda x: x.weekday()
get_weekday = np.vectorize(weekday_func)
get_weekday(dat)
```